# How to solve cannot find module error when using vercel/ncc

Tags: node.js, vercel

I am trying to compile a node js application into a single file using [vercel/ncc](https://github.com/vercel/ncc)

I followed the instructions, but when I run the generated file, it fails with the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypto.node'
```

Any idea how to fix this?